# SublimeText3 better goto definition for Ruby stdlib

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to have library goto definition code work in SublimeText 3? Ie. I want to include my documentation and the stdlib in my definitions when I click goto definition ala RubyMine's functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Mac and have [Dash.app](http://kapeli.com/dash), then you use a keypress in Sublime Text 3 automatically open the Ruby documentation for any given method. It works for the Ruby stdlib as well as for Rails or any gem that you add to Dash.app.

Simply install the DashDoc package via Package Control: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DashDoc

Comment: You rock. Thanks.